# ICS: Add Google Contact Group To Home Screen

Tags: contacts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen

Please note I'm using Ice Cream Sandwich.

I'd like to add a shortcut to a Google Contacts Group such as 'Co-Workers' to my home screen.  Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that there is a native way to do this in ICS.  However, you could use the **folders** feature in ICS to add multiple contacts to the home screen and group them into a single folder.  Not exactly what you're looking for, but this seems like it is the best native (non-3rd party) solution in ICS.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.